# Creating tkinter Progress Bar for Windows CMD Command

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter

I have a simple project in python 3.8.1 and tkinter with some buttons to execute system action like windows file explorer and copy files and it's working fine, except the CMD window appearing.

Is there any method to create tkinter progress bar for processing showing when executing CMD command?

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()

def open_file():
    os.system('start explorer.exe')

def copy_file():
    input_val1 = t1.get("1.0","end-1c")
    input_val2 = t2.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(input_val1)
    print(input_val2)
    os.system('copy '+input_val1+'     '+input_val2)

t1 = Text(root, height = 1, width = 10)
t1.pack()

t2 = Text(root, height = 1, width = 10)
t2.pack()

b1 = Button(root, text="open file explorer",       command = lambda: open_file())
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(root, text="copy files", command = lambda: copy_file())
b2.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: for single comand you could show only 0% at start and 100% at the end - you can't control command in CMD to display values between 0% and 100%. For many commands in `for`-loop you can change progressbar in every loop but you can display (as percent) how many commands already finished.